Manipulate cache in angular for PWA API calls
I am trying to make a part of my angular app offline capable. The project has already the package @angular/pwa installed and the ngsw-config.json is succesfully caching API calls:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
   ...

  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-forms",
      "urls": [
        "/api/Books",
        "/api/Videos",
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "1d",
        "timeout": "10s"
      }
    }
  ]
}

My question now: How do I manipulate these cached API calls? For example, if a user is adding a book, the book cache should be updated. The only thing I found is using directly the CacheStorage API. This API works, but I need to specify exactly the name of the cache and API URL (no regex matching). Even worse, the cache name has some prefixes in it:
Angular PWA and caching API
What is the angular way here? Is this just not implemented yet? Am I doing something really strange and there is a better way?
